# reducing error between two complex matrix to certain tolerance limit

Tags: matlab, matrix, complex-numbers

I have two complex matrices and I want to reduce the error between two by optimization in matlab.The first complex matrix is experimentally obtained and the other is estimated one.If the two matrices are real than it can be easily done using

error = sqrt(sum(x-y).^2)

But since x and y are complex numbers, how can we reduce the error to certain tolerance limit.

Comment: `sqrt(sum(real(x-y).^2) + sum(imag(x-y).^2))` ? Or equivalently `sqrt(sum(abs(x-y).^2))`

Comment: By using this formula the real and imaginary terms may interchange and not remain unique because if we change the position of real and imaginary part then also there absolute value remain same. I want both complex vectors real and imaginary part to be within some tolerance limit.

Comment: With this formula, the error is zero if and only if both real parts are equal and both imaginary parts are equal